# Wrong Query Generated with EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use a simple where clause to retrieve data from a SQL Server. However the generated query is incorrect.This query worked perfectly with EF Core 2.2 but with EF Core 3 it throws an exception.

```
    public async Task<List<CharacterReplacements>> GetReplacementsAsync(int? replacementSetId)
    {
        var replacementQuery = _context.CharacterReplacements.AsQueryable();

        if (replacementSetId.HasValue)
        {
            replacementQuery = replacementQuery.Where(r => r.CharacterReplacementSetID == replacementSetId.Value); // .AsQueryable();
        }

        var replacementList = await replacementQuery.ToListAsync();

        return replacementList;
    }
```

---

```
[Serializable]
[Table("CharacterReplacementSets", Schema = "SYSTEM")]
public class CharacterReplacementSets
{
    [NavigationPropertyKey]
    [Key]
    public int CharacterReplacementSetID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CharacterReplacements> CharacterReplacements { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FormatField> FormatFields { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    public string DefaultEncoding { get; set; } // Default character set
    public string DefaultCharacter { get; set; }
    public CharacterReplacementSets()
    {
        CharacterReplacements = new List<CharacterReplacements>();
    }
}
```

---

```
[Serializable]
[Table("CharacterReplacements", Schema = "SYSTEM")]
public class CharacterReplacements
{
    [NavigationPropertyKey]
    [Key]
    public int CharacterReplacementID { get; set; }
    public char OriginalCharacter { get; set; }
    public string ReplacementCharacter { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CharacterReplacementSets")]
    public int CharacterReplacementSetID { get; set; }
}
```

Expected result- Retrieve all CharacterReplacements where the replacementSetId equals the provided replacementSetId.

Actual result- 
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'CharacterReplacementSetsCharacterReplacementSetID'.

Could someone kindly help me out with this?

Comment: Please run a SQL Trace for 2.2 and then 3.0. Please update your question to show the exact SQL generated for both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the specific query, but the model mapping.

First, the `ForeignKey` attribute here

```
[ForeignKey("CharacterReplacementSets")]
public int CharacterReplacementSetID { get; set; }
```

has no effect. When applied to navigation property, it's supposed to specify the FK **property** name. And when applied on FK property as here, it's supposed to specify the navigation **property** name. `CharacterReplacements` has no navigation property called `CharacterReplacementSets`, so the attribute is simply ignored. It would be good if EF Core generates runtime error to indicate a mapping problem, but it doesn't.

The attribute has been ignored in EF Core 1.x / 2.x as well. However it worked because the name of the property `CharacterReplacementSetID` matches the name of the PK of `CharacterReplacementSets`. This is no more true for EF Core 3.0 due to the following breaking change - [The foreign key property convention no longer matches same name as the principal property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#fkp).

So remove the incorrect and misleading `ForeignKey` attribute, and configure the FK property by either `HasForeignKey` fluent API (my preferred):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CharacterReplacementSets>()
    .HasMany(e => e.CharacterReplacements)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.CharacterReplacementSetID);
```

or with `ForegnKey` attribute on navigation property (or inverse navigation property when there is no navigation property as here):

```
[ForeignKey("CharacterReplacementSetID")]
public ICollection<CharacterReplacements> CharacterReplacements { get; set; }
```

Note that you might have similar problem with `FormatField` and other entities using similar named FKs w/o navigation properties.

Another way to avoid this issue is to use singular entity class names like `CharacterReplacementSet`, `CharacterReplacement` etc. because the `[entity name] + ID` still matches EF Core conventions. And in general singular class names are better/preferable, even just for readability.

Comment: Awesome. Solved my problem! Thanks for the helpful explaination